# How to add a new line (\n) between each file being concatenated

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

How should I modify this line to add a new line (\n) between each file being concatenated?

```
find /disk/data/source/* -name '*.xml' -exec cat {} \; > /home/userid/merged-file.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find accepts multiple `-exec`s in one command. For example:

```
find /disk/data/source/* -name '*.xml' -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "" \; > /home/userid/merged-file.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk instead of cat:

```
find /disk/data/source/* -name '*.xml' \
    -exec awk 'NR!=FNR&&FNR==1{print ""} 1' {} + > /home/userid/merged-file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `find`, try this:

```
find /disk/data/source/* -name '*.xml' -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \; > /home/userid/merged-file.xml
```

And if you want to get rid of the extra newline at the end, you can add `| head -n-1`.